# So close to getting this layout down, RelativeLayout/LinearLayout woes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I posted this question a week ago and didn't really understand what the people who responded meant. I was hoping to get some clarification.

**EDIT:**
I've gotten really close; actually, the closest I've been yet. This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="52dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/holder"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contactPicture"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:maxHeight="48dp"
            android:maxWidth="48dp"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:minWidth="48dp"
            tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorReceived"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myPicture"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:maxHeight="48dp"
            android:maxWidth="48dp"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:minWidth="48dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textColor="@color/dateColorReceived"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/media"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

        <View   android:id="@+id/gifView"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textColor="@color/dateColorReceived"/>

 </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

However, some messages look wrong. They just get really warped. Can't seem to figure out why. Plus, `@+id/myPicture` doesn't always stay to the right.

It's current state:
[image: screenshotOfCurrentState]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the desired result?

Comment: just use table layout With table rows it will solve your problem

Comment: @tobor I don't have a picture of the desired result. Ideally, I want it to look like it does now, except the body text should be in line with the `contactPicture` and `myPicture`.

Comment: @Mahfa How would I do that?

Comment: OK, now this should be the custom row of a ListView. I suppose you're having two custom rows. Or are you alternatively moving the picture via code?

Comment: Sorry , you have to use a linearlayout with vertical orientation For root layout and place two linear layouts with horizontal orientation in it :-)

Comment: @Tobor The pictures are moved via this xml layout.

Comment: @Tobor I guess what I'm trying to get is this: [CardsUI](http://www.droid-life.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Sliding-2.jpg). Look at the left-most image.

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myPicture"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:maxHeight="48dp"
        android:maxWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contactPicture"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="48dp"
        android:maxWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/myPicture"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactPicture"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorReceived"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/body"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/dateColorReceived"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:id="@+id/media"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <View android:layout_below="@+id/media"
        android:id="@+id/gifView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gifView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/dateColorReceived"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Don't use linearlayout try creating the layout using relative layout only and align view wrt each other

Comment: This is what happens when I use this: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/2oUMGGy.png). The problem using just a `RelativeLayout` means I lose the full width of the "cards". I know it has something to do with `@+id/holder` and possibly even `@+id/background`.

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect recent advancements. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting what you are looking for because the way you layed out your Views renders the Relative Layout useless.

The good news is that what you are trying to accomplish is fairly easy.

`LinearLayout` - A linear layout places child views one after the other, with some simple size control.

`RelativeLayout` - A relative layout organizes child views based on relationships to eachother and to the parent layout.

With this in mind you need to start laying out your views. this is what we are trying to get:

```
---------------------------------
|---------                      | <-- parent layout
||       |                      |
||       |                      |
||image1 | Message              |
||       | timeStamp            |
||       |                      |
|--------|                      |
|-------------------------------|
```

Now that you know what you want to accomplish, you can start implementing it.

1. Create a `RelativeLayout` to hold all the views
2. Create an `ImageView` inside the parent layout and use android:layout_centerVertical=true
3. Create a `TextView` for the message and align it to the vertical center of the image1 `ImageView`
4. Create a `TextView` for the timestamp and align it to be below the message textview

Once all of that is done. you can add this layout as a `ListView` child view or into a series of views within a LinearLayout

Comment: I've edited my post after following some of your suggestions. I'm really close now.